# Two columns in Python DataFrame that are lists, need to match first column as header with second column as data

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I converted a json into a csv with pandas, no problem there. here is the json: https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/json/ovation_aurora_latest.json

That returned a dataframe with two columns that I am interested in using, one that contains the list of a string of names [latitude, longitude, aurora] and the other that contains the integer data for those names ie [34,25,2].

How do I create a new dataframe with the first list as the column headers, and the data from the second list as the corresponding rows of data? I tried a few things, but nothing works so far.

I can isolate the rows without an issue, but I do not know how to then perform the operations as stated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it using the dataframe `apply` method. Something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/json/ovation_aurora_latest.json")
df.head(5)

result = pd.DataFrame()
coordinates = df["coordinates"]

result["Longitude"] = coordinates.apply(lambda x: x[0])
result["Latitude"] = coordinates.apply(lambda x: x[1])
result["Aurora"] = coordinates.apply(lambda x: x[2])

result.head(5)
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. I haven't gotten into lambda at this point, as I understand it it functions as basically an inline function correct? So it takes the single argument x and returns x[1]? Could you explain that any further?

Comment: For sure @DrewGIS. With Lambda functions we can declare implicit functions in Python.  On this answer, for each row `x` in the `coordinates` dataframe, the lambda functions receive a list of coordinates `x` and return the respective list elements `x[0]`, `x[1]`, and `x[2]` for the `result` data-frame.